# Create three image button to show web view if I click one button

Tags: android

I want to show three image button to show web view if I click one button. But ,when I create three image button by linear layout, it is not OK because I want to show if I clicked button under image button menu. However, now, it going new window.

**my webview.xml**

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/imageButtonHomeSelector"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@drawable/icon_home_config"
       android:onClick="imageButtonHomeSelector"


       />
<WebView
       android:id="@+id/webView1"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:layout_marginTop="96dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**my mainactivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Button Homebutton, LoginButton, SettingButton;


  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Context context = this;

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WebViewActivity.class);

    startActivity(intent);


    addListenerHomeButton();
   // addListenerLoginButton();
   // addListenerSettingButton();

  }


 public void addListenerHomeButton() {

    Homebutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonHomeSelector);
    Homebutton.setFocusable(true);
    Homebutton.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

    Homebutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WebViewActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

    });

}

  public void addListenerLoginButton() {

    LoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonLoginSelector);
    // LoginButton.setFocusable(true);
    LoginButton.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

    LoginButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

    });

  }

  public void addListenerSettingButton() {

     SettingButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonSettingSelector);

     SettingButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SettingActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

         }

     });

   }
}
```

Comment: *I want to show if I clicked button under image button menu* -  If I understand correctly, then you can't show the buttons after you start a new Activity. I think you should look into using Fragments

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you have to do is to remove these lines from `onCreate`

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Context context = this;

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);

    // You are starting the Activity always without doing anything else
    //Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WebViewActivity.class);

    //startActivity(intent);


    addListenerHomeButton();
   // addListenerLoginButton();
   // addListenerSettingButton();

}
```

Then you will be able to click on the button (if visible).

Answer (score 0):

You can setup onClick for each of the three buttons that triggers the same action of the button click.